# Delay in location update on iOS 8 using google maps sdk for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6, google-maps-sdk-ios

There is a 30sec - 2min delay in fetching my location on an iOS 8 app am developing using google maps sdk for iOS. Issue is that this does not happen all the time, sometimes my location is fetched as soon as the app opens and sometimes it takes about 2 minutes for the location to be updated. This is not happening in iOS 7.x.x.

I have added the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in the Info.plist file and updated the code so that location manager calls the requestAlwaysAuthorization method.

Any idea what may be causing the delay in the location to be updated?

Comment: Where do you calling requestAlwaysAuthorization? It should be in the init function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where I saw this mentioned but iOS may do an optimization where location is not updated if the device has been still for a while.  This seems to introduce a delay in getting the current location.  Cycling the CLLocationManager seems to solve the problem.  I call startUpdatingLocation/stopUpdatingLocation/startUpdatingLocation when I need to find the current location fast.  Seems to get the current location quick (less than 1s) on iOS 7.1/8.3 on iPhone4s/iPhone5s/iPodTouch5G.